# How to print a new value of a checkbox after having checked it?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I built a form in which I populated checkboxes with values stored in a PostGreSQL database (you can see the snippet).  The checkbox are checked or not checked automatically.
Now, if I choose another value of the checkbox, I'd like to display it in an "alert" or "console.log" print.
How could I do in Javascript or Jquery ?

Thanks you very much for the help !

```
    <div class="form-row">
    <div id="man-compo" class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Composition (le texte hagiographique est composé de) :</label><br>          
         <?php
          foreach ($checked116 as $value) {  
             $array12 = array("Textes historiographiques","Actes de la pratique","Textes grammaticaux","Lettres et ars dictaminis","Vers et inscriptions métriques","Lexique","Comput","Algèbre et géométrie","Autres");
             $checked = "";
             if(in_array($value, $array12)){
                $checked = "checked";
                  echo '<input type="checkbox" id= "checked-man-compo-compo-1" name="checkedmancompocompo1[]" value="'.$value.'" '.$checked.' > '.$value.' <br/>';
                }
             }
           foreach ($array12 as $i) {
             $checked = "";
             if(in_array($i, $checked116)){
             }
             else {
             echo '<input type="checkbox" id= "notchecked-man-compo-compo-1" name="notcheckedmancompocompo1[]" value="'.$i.'" '.$checked.' > '.$i.' <br/>';
             }
           }
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of what you're trying to do in plain JavaScript which you can mody/apply to your code.

```js
//get all checkboxes beginning with id 'checkbox'
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll( "[ id^=checkbox ]" );

//add event listener to each checkbox, upon being checked/unchecked to print out value
for ( let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++ ) {
 checkboxes[ i ].addEventListener( "change", function() {
  
   console.log( checkboxes[ i ].value );
  });
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox1"> checkbox 1 </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value=1>

<label for="checkbox2"> checkbox 2 </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value=2>

<label for="checkbox3"> checkbox 3 </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value=3>

<label for="checkbox4"> checkbox 4 </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" value=4>
```

I hope this is of help to you.

Comment: Great that's perfect, you saved me ! Thank you very much for your help